# Fast way to populate a vector with dynamically instantiated objects

Tags: c++

I need to populate a std::vector with dynamically instantiated objects.

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<MyObject*> m_objects;
    //...
}
```

This is the use case I need with naive code:

```
void MyClass::MyFunc1(std::vector<MyType> data)
{
    for (auto&& d : data)
        m_objects.push_back(new MyObject(d));
}
```

So I take an array of n data elements in parameter, and construct n objects using these data elements. I put all elements in the vector.

I would like to find some fast way to do it, mostly by avoiding doing lot of new and lot of calls to push_back. I ended with the following solution, dividing execution time by a factor of two:

```
void MyClass::MyFunc2(std::vector<MyType> data)
{
    size_t size = data.size();
    MyObject *array = new MyObject[size];
    MyObject **parray = new MyObject*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        parray[i] = &array[i];

    m_objects.insert(m_objects.end(), &parray[0], &parray[size]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        m_objects[i]->data = data[i];
}
```

So I create all objects at once, and put them all at once using insert. One overhead is the creation of the array of pointers in order to be able to insert pointers on the objects instead of copying objects into the vector. Another is the need to manually construct the object afterward.

I am open to better solution, including using an other structure than a vector. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at `reserve()`. And do you really need a `vector` of pointers instead of a `vector` of objects? It gives you additional level of indirection and memory fragmentation.

Comment: I already tried reserve() and you are right it add a little help.

Comment: Yes I need this vector of pointers. The "MyObject" objects are, in a way a big graph, each object pointing on some others. I need this vector of pointer in addition in order to track all items of the graph easily.

Comment: Have you measured this "little help"? It's interesting to compare code without `reserve()`, code with `reserve()` and code with `insert()`.

Comment: If you really need a vector of pointers, e.g., because of dynamic polymorphism, consider using smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I did. My first example is a little faster with reserve(), but still slower that the second one with or without reserve()

Comment: @harfangeek _The `MyObject` objects are, in a way a big graph, each object pointing on some others._ You can have objects (not pointers) in a vector and still they can point to other objects, when you reserve vector memory. This solution is a bit fragile, since the vector may not reallocate then, but will be more efficient.

Comment: How much faster or slower? If you have a large graph with some non-trivial operations on it, won't this cost be negligible after amortization?

Comment: @Daniel I considered this solution but I was not sure of the consistency of the items addresses in the vector. Will I be sure that if a MyObject is pointing on another in the vector, the pointer will stay valid all the time, even when the vector is heavy modification (objects removed/added)?

Comment: BTW, if you need to work with large graphs and care about efficiency, there might be more appropriate ways how to implement this. Such as representing graphs by adjacency matrices (possibly bit-compressed) with additional information about nodes stored in plain vector/arrays. Some existing libraries can help, such as GraphBLAS, that can even perform operations with graphs by very fast matrix operations internally.

Comment: @Evg You're right this part of the code is not the slower by far, but I'm still interested to know what would be a good solution nowadays.

Comment: If the vector has to increase its capacity, all pointers (iterators) will be invalidated.

Comment: @harfangeek Alternatively, you can store indices of objects in a vector instead of pointers. Indices remain valid even if vector capacity grows. You can also save memory space, if for instance 32bit indices are enough, in contrast to 64bit pointers.

Answer (score 3):

A simple suggestion is to store objects in the vector, not pointers, and use `reserve()` to preallocate space:

```
std::vector<MyObject> m_objects;    

void MyFunc1(std::vector<MyType> data)
{
    m_objects.reserve(m_objects.size() + data.size());
    for (auto&& d : data)
        m_objects.emplace_back(d);
}
```

If you need pointers, use smart pointers and `reserve`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objects;    

void MyFunc1(std::vector<MyType> data)
{
    m_objects.reserve(m_objects.size() + data.size());
    for (auto&& d : data)
        m_objects.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObject>(d));
}
```